# Crud Ajax Laravel 5.*

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Estou com um probleminha. Eu estou fazendo um crud com Ajax + Laravel. "Tudo" esta funcionando, mais exceto que quando eu atualizo um dado, ele também cadastra. Bem Veja com eu estou fazendo.
Tenho um Butão que eu tenho um id chamado dashboard_cadastrar_categoria. Esse id serve para que eu recupere com jQuery e aciono o evento click.

```
 <button id="dashboard_cadastrar_categoria" type="button" class="btn btn-primary butao_categoria">Cadastrar</button>
```

Mais quando eu vou atualizar eu mudo esse id com jQuery para update_ .

```
 $('.butao_categoria').attr('id', 'update_');
```

Quando eu atualizo ele atualiza e cadastra logo após. O que poderia ser?

Método Ajax para acessar o método store no meu controller Categoria.php

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#success').hide();
$(document).ready(function () {
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $("#dashboard_cadastrar_categoria").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/administracao/categoria/store',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, nome: $("#nome_categoria").val()},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {

                // console.log(data);

                $("#nome_categoria").val('');
                $('#success').show();
                $('#success').text('Categoria Cadastrada com Sucesso');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#success').fadeOut('slow');
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

Esse metodo funciona mais desconfio que depois que eu atualizo ele entre nesse método mais não sei o por que.

Medoto Ajax que acessa o controller Categoria.php para para pegar as informações para editar.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.categoria_editar').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/administracao/categoria/edit/' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
    }).done(function (e) {
        $('#cadastro_categoria').modal('show');
        $('.butao_categoria').attr('id', 'update_');
        $('.butao_categoria').text('Update');
        $('#dashboard_categoria_id').val(e.id);
        $('#nome_categoria').val(e.nome_categoria);
    });
});

});
```

E por ultimo o metodo ajax que acessa o controller para atualizar

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');


$(".butao_categoria").click(function () {
    var nome_catg = $('#nome_categoria').val();
    var id_categ = $('#dashboard_categoria_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/administracao/categoria/update',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, nome_categoria: nome_catg, id_categ: id_categ},
        dataType: 'JSON',

        success: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Controller :
Método Store:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')){
        $categoria = new Categoria;
        $categoria->create([
            'nome_categoria'    => $request->get('nome_categoria'),

        ]);

        if($categoria){

            return response()->json(['success' => 'success' , 'categoria'   =>  Categoria::where('nome_categoria' , $request->get('nome_categoria'))->first()]);
        }

    }

    return response()->json(['response' => 'This is get method']);
}
```

Método Editar

```
 public function edit($id){
    $categoria = Categoria::findOrFail($id);
    return response()->json($categoria);
}
```

Método Update

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $categoria = Categoria::findOrFail($request->get('id_categ'));

    $result = $categoria->update([
        'nome_categoria' => $request->get('nome_categoria'),
    ]);
    if($result){
        return response()->json('sucesso');
    }
}
```

Comment: Posta o código do controller também.

Comment: Prontinho. @Andre Gusmão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você fez uma confusão tremenda no seu código.. Quando você inicia o seu código, o javascript é carregado e dispara um evento store pro button de id "#dashboard_cadastrar_categoria", quando você vai alterar o registro você pega o button pela class

```
$('.butao_categoria').attr('id', 'update_');
```

e edita o id, para que na hora que clicar não vá mais pra o evento de store, até aí a intenção está correta, porém o evento onClick não vai mais saír daquela button, quando você muda o id de nada adianta, toda vez que você clicar nequela button o trecho de código que está ali dentro vai ser executado. Então resumindo quando você click em alterar ele executa o primeiro evento que foi escrito para o "#dashboard_cadastrar_categoria"(store) e depois executa pela class ".butao_categoria" o evento de update.

Te dou 4 opções para resolução desse problema:

**1º (demorada e eficaz)** - Você pode elaborar uma outra lógica de maneira que o fluxo corra mais naturalmente, isso que você fez soa como gambiarra. Demorada, porque você terá que pensar .

**2º (demorada e eficiente)** - você pode usar datatables, tem métodos já prontos que te ajudam a pegar os dados da linha, sem precisar fazer uma requisição ajax adicional. Demorada, porque irá ter que estudar a api.

**3º (rápida e eficaz)** - Você pode colocar 2 buttons um pra editar e um pra salvar quando for salvar esconde o de editar e quando for editar esconde o de salvar.

**4º (rápida e eficaz)** -  você pode ainda fazer dessa forma:

```
var evento=1;
// 1 para store
// 2 para update

$('.butao_categoria').click(function () {
    if(evento == 1){
        //Dispara evento para salvar o objeto
    }else{
        //Dispara evento para alterar o objeto
    }
});
```

**OBS.** Sempre procure por soluções nas quais o código fique limpo e que você consiga entender o fluxo de forma natural.

Comment: Perfeito. Eu ja usei a Api do datatables Yajra acho que é esse nome. Mais amanhã eu vou ver isso ai e te dou um retorno se tudo deu certo e marco como resolvido a sua solução. Desde já sou grato pela ajuda